# Issue with date-picker duration

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, debugging

There is some kind of "campaign duration" which means you are able to choose date between first and last day in month. If you choose date which is not between first and last day in month, for example some date from next month, the Backend API will return an "Input param error".

Current works like when I choose the last date inside date selector(30th day in month), the Backend API will return an "Input param error".
That means he count 30th day like 1st day in next month.
I should Change date selection with one day less.

Question is where in code I should subtract for 1-day that "endDate"-property?

HTML part of this modal in which is this date picker:
(You can see endDate there, I want to subtract that endDate for 1-day)

```
  <!-- startDate/endDate -->
        <div class="nano-f-r nano-f">
            <nano-date-picker [(startDate)]="campaignDto.dtoData.startDate"
                              [(endDate)]="campaignDto.dtoData.endDate"
                              [intervalMode]="campaignDto.id === 'new' ? dpIntervalFuture : dpIntervalBoth"
                              [maxIntervalDurationInMonths]="2"
                              style="height: 30px"></nano-date-picker>
        </div>
    </div>
```

nano-date-picker component:

```
   public isDaySelected(day: MonthDay): boolean {
    return this.isDateRange === true
        ? day.startDate === this.datePicker.startDate || day.endDate === this.datePicker.endDate
        : day.startDate === this.datePicker.startDate;
}

public ngOnChanges(): void {
    const startDate = this.startDate ? moment(this.startDate).format() : moment().startOf('day').format();
    const endDate = this.endDate ? moment(this.endDate).format() : moment(startDate).endOf('day').format();
    this.datePicker = new DatePicker(startDate, endDate);
    this.setDatePicker();

    if (this.continiousDatesValue !== null) {
        this.continiousDatesValueMoment = moment(this.continiousDatesValue);
    }
    if (this.previousDatesValue !== null) {
        this.previousDatesValueMoment = moment(this.previousDatesValue);
    }
}

private onDatesChange(): void {
    this.startDateChange.emit(this.datePicker.startDate);
    this.endDateChange.emit(this.datePicker.endDate);
    this.startEndDateChange.emit({startDate: this.datePicker.startDate, endDate: this.datePicker.endDate});
    this.isOpen = false;
}


public setRange(day: MonthDay): void {
    if (this.isDateRange === true) {
        this.datePicker.setRange(day, () => this.onDatesChange())
    } else {
        this.datePicker.setSingleDate(day, () => this.onDatesChange())
    }
}
```

Here is how looks that date picker:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should subtract day in both `ngOnChanges` and in `onDatesChange`.

### EDIT

You should subtract you date here:

```
this.datePicker = new DatePicker(startDate, endDate);
```

This end date need to be subtracted like this:

```
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() - 1);
this.datePicker = new DatePicker(startDate, endDate);
```

Comment: @James Delaney or you can subtract prior to sending to API. It is up to you but the best is to subtract as soon as you get new date. Here: `this.datePicker = new DatePicker(startDate, endDate);` There is no need to subtract in onDatesChanged if you subtract it here.

Comment: Hey @Joe I subtract on both place, and still on api is sent 31first July instead of 30th. 
On the first place I subtracted like this: moment(this.endDate).subtract(1, "day").format()

And in the onDatesChange() function I subtracted also.

I console logged that two dates and they are successfully subtracted but on api he still send date which is not subtracted.

Problem is cus I should subtracted endDate on the other place.

Comment: @James Delaney you must check which date are you sending (prior or after changing) and to be sure it is not changed in the meantime

Comment: Thank you very much for reply and advice I will check.